# Looking for a good way to include php code in posts, but using special include markup rather than direct php code

Tags: plugins, php, code

Ok, bit of a weird one... I want to include php code on one of my pages within the content by adding something like:

```
Welcome to the payment page
[paymentform]

Blash blah vlha...
```

And then [paymentform] resolves to a bit of code either somewhere on the filesystem or within the database and handled by a settings page in the backend.

I didn't want to use the exec-php plugin for several reasons - mainly I don't want our client messing with the php code, secondly there are limitations using that with the visual editor etc..etc..

Cheers,
John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Shortcodes API http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Agreed, shortcodes are the best fit for this.